# Deploy large code base to new Salesforce dev org

Tags: deployment, migration, salesforce, force.com

Currently we have multiple users trying to develope code on same application in salesforce. We have a Product already in place and it already have lots of code. What we are trying to do is find an easy to use mechanism that can be used to deploy our central code base to multiple developer unrelated orgs.

What we have -

1. SVN Code base where all of code has been stored.
2. Multiple unrelated dev orgs.
3. Current Org and code base have lots of Apex, Pages, Email templates, reports, dashboards, Workflow , Profiles, triggers and most of the standard as well as Custom Salesforce functionalities.

What we want to do -
1. A simplified mechanism or way which can be used to deploy all of org to some unrealted dev / partner orgs.

What we have tried - 
1. We tried the same using Eclipse and it takes almost 6-7 hours to complete activity and that too has a probability of missing out things due to dependecies among multiple compinents. A very big headache with this approach.
2. Use Ant Migration tool. Using Force.com Migration tool and Ant commands, we tried deploying for first time to unrelated org. But it gave at least 400 -500 errors over command prompt. Not sure how to make this work. Do we have easer way or we need to go ahead and solve each issue one by one.

We dont have provision for Change Sets or Sandbox / Production org as we are creating a package for multiple users.
Please let me know about any other possible ways that can be used to migrate huge code base (standard + Custom SF components) to any unrelated dev org.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kaushik

Answer (score 0):

When we need to deploy SF project to new org manually (or update current one manually), we usually deploy parts of a project in such sequence:

1. static res
2. labels
3. groups
4. roles
5. letterhead
6. documents
7. OBJETCS
8. tabs
9. apps
10. email
11. classes
12. pages
13. components
14. layouts
15. triggers
16. workflows
17. reports
18. dashbords
19. homepage layouts
20. homepage components
21. profiles
22. permission sets

This allows us to to avoid mistakes related to dependencies in the components of the project. Also we use some tools for continuous integration (e.g. Jenkins which deploys all  changes (which are commited to repository) to CI org and every night deploys builds on QA org).